# Jenkinsfile and groovy script - Unexpected End of File

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I need to have a one-liner sh script such as this

`if ! [-s filename.txt ] then echo 'don'\''t do something' exit 2 fi`

but when I put this in `sh " <>"`  I am getting the following error

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/<BLA_BLA>/script.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Not sure how to fix it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you need to escape the backslash inside the `sh` block, so for example:

`sh "if ! [-s filename.txt ] then echo 'don'\\''t do something' exit 2 fi"`

Then there is probably a problem with the oneliner script you posted as it doesn't work in plain bash for me either.

In the pipeline, you can use multiline string with `"""`, if I reformat the script you posted, it works correctly:

```
sh """
    if ! [ -s filename.txt ]; then
        echo 'don'\\''t do something'
        exit 2
    fi
"""
```

the output then is:

```
+ '[' -s filename.txt ']'
+ echo 'don'\''t do something'
don't do something
+ exit 2
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
```

Would that work for you?